# How do I overlay a transparent color on top of a div and position loading... text in the absolute center of the div?

Tags: css

```
<div class="square loading"></div>

square {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

loading {
  ...
}
```

I'm trying to:

1. Overlay black color on top of div with 50% transparency (so background is still visible).
2. Place `Loading...` text in the absolute center of the div.

How do I achieve this with pure CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

display flex is your friend

```css
.square {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
}

.loading:after {
   content: '...loading';
   position: absolute;
   top:0;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
   left: 0;
   background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='loading square'></div>
```

Comment: That is perfect, Singh. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you..

```css
.square {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
  <div class="loading">Loading...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```css
.square {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  position:relative;
}
.square::after {
  color: #fff;
  content: "loading...";
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="square loading"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid: #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
}
.loader {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(127, 127, 127, 0.6);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  z-index: -1;
}
.loader.active {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="loader active">Loading</div>
  <div class="content">Hai</div>  
</div>
```

In this snippet, you can see the `loader` div. You can toggle its mode `ON/OFF` by toggling the class `active`. Also, the content in the loader (Now it is `Loading`) div will always be in the center. No matter what the content and its width or height are. Because the `flexbox` is used here.

Also, the overlay can be changed by changing the background of the `loader`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a  `div` with content and a `div` with class overlay. you can try like this.

```css
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam laoreet nisl vel eros pulvinar, eu ultrices lorem interdum. Donec maximus massa ullamcorper est egestas faucibus et ac ligula. </p>
  <div class="overlay">Loading...</div>
</div>
```